# visual studio code necesita un driver propio para conectar con mysql server en localhost?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando conectarme a un servidor MySQL en localhost. Este es mi código, y el terminal me muestra el siguiente error. ¿Alguien sabe si Visual Studio Code requiere un controlador de conexión??

```
terminal log:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ventas
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
at ConexionBD.main(ConexionBD.java:13)

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexionBD {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Establecer la conexión a la base de datos
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ventas";
        String usuario = "root";
        String contraseña = "root1234";

        try (Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario,                             contraseña)) {
            System.out.println("Conexión exitosa a la base de datos");

            // Realizar operaciones con la base de datos aquí

          } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }introducir el código aquí
         // La conexión se cierra automáticamente al salir del bloque try-with-                             resources
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos, el idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code es un editor, no un IDE, por lo que debes estructurar bien tu proyecto, la mejor manera es trabajar con un gestor de paquetes como es `maven` o `gradle`.
Ahora en tu caso debes de estar compilando o si estas usando el compilador de VS Code debe estar compilando asi: `javac *.java` y esta bien lo que esta mal es el modo en el que se ejecuta, la ejecución normal es: `java program`, pero cuando usas librerias debes argumentar la libreria mas, el resultado seria:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:. program
```

tambien recordar que debes tener la [libreria](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.33) en tu proyecto que en este caso es el mysql-connector, si te fue de ayuda la respuesta puedes marcarla como respuesta acertada.